# WPF: Understanding ModernUI LinkNavigator

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I am a newb. First time with C# and WPF w/ ModernUI Framework.

I'm trying to understand how I would properly initialize another `ModernWindow` as well as destroy the object when the back arrow is clicked. The window loads fine but going back doesn't destroy the object. Do I have to handle a close event somewhere to properly dispose of it?

```
public void navigateMediaSelection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ModernWindow window = new ModernWindow();

    try
    {
        window.LinkNavigator.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/MediaView/MovieView.xaml", UriKind.Relative), this);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage(error.Message, FirstFloor.ModernUI.Resources.NavigationFailed, MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears ModernWindow is not the right object for navigation. Rather, use BBCodeBlock.

Updated code:

```
public void navigateMediaSelection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BBCodeBlock window = new BBCodeBlock();

    try
    {
        window.LinkNavigator.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/MediaView/MovieView.xaml", UriKind.Relative), this);

    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage(error.Message, FirstFloor.ModernUI.Resources.NavigationFailed, MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }

}
```